# Jquery disable button until ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in the middle of this site here http://offline.raileisure.com/

the booking section on the right hand side, I need to be able to disable the book now button until the date,duration and adult and children numbers are set..

I can't work out how to do it..

Any ideas ??

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the `change` handler on all your form elements... for example:

```
$(':input').change(function() {
    var complete;

    // check if your form is complete here

    // assumes the id of the button is 'bookNowButton'
    if (!complete) $('#bookNowButton').attr('disabled', true);
    else $('#bookNowButton').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

To simplify the enable/disable functionality I'd also perhaps suggest changing your "Book Now" button to an `<input type="image" />` instead.

Comment: have a +1 to counter the -1 that @Asad gave your perfectly good answer.

Comment: NB: in jQuery 1.6 you could just do: `$('#bookNowButton').prop('disabled', !complete)`

Comment: @Alnitak ahh interesting - didn't know that :) Thanks!

Comment: you should also trap `keyup`, `mouseup`, and (if supported) `paste` events, since on some input types `change` isn't fired until the focus changes.  See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/n9RvX/

Comment: @Jhon Sorry, I thought it were you who down vote me I am new in this site so accept my apologies.